# how to manipulate a frame in a TCP handshaking

Tags: sockets, tcp, frame

The following sequence shows the process of a TCP connection being established:

- Frame 1: This is a request to the server to synchronize the sequence numbers requested by the client.
- Frame 2: In the second frame, the server, sends an ACK and a SYN.
- Frame 3: In the third frame, the client sends an ACK.

I'd like to know how I can get the first frame and identify source IP and source Port.
I'd like to add this address (IP + port), in the frame 2 made by me, and send it in place of the normal handshakin.

I studied and learned how to make a server and a client in VBScript using TCP properts.
This works fine and I can send any string which I want to the server.

But what I really want to do now, is have access to the frames and
identify parameter settings within it, in real time, as a sniffer does too.

I do not want to use a sniffer to this, I would like to make a program that in addition to work as sniffer,
also recognize some frame parameter settings and add them in a ready frame and sends it to the client.

someone could help me with some document or even some tips on how I could make this program...
would also like to know what would be the recommended language for this task... I'm suspicious that with VBScript, will not be possible to make it.

Comment: If you're using TCP ports in any high-level language, you're probably already relying on the underlying TCP stack to create the connection for you. You won't even be notified until after all these steps have already happened. You need to use raw sockets and essentially write a TCP stack yourself. How to do this in detail is a bit broad, but start by research raw sockets.

Comment: hi EJP, thank you for the clue and for having revised my text and too...
I understood the difference between conventional socket and the raw socket...
I'm already researching about it and I think I'll build my program using C. If possible, I'll post here, the evolution of my learning, as an example of my question.   Thank you very much.